# Date modified changes on network folder when right clicked (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, date-modified

Wierd thing I've noticed recently.  Just right clicking a folder (which opens the context menu) then closing it again will change its date modified to the current date and time.

I created two (empty) folders.. waited a bit, then right clicked folder "2"... and the date changed to the current time:

[image]

Wondering if it is somekind of (buggy) explorer extension that might be causing this, or if others are also seeing it.

Autoruns lists these:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem even with a network drive on v1709 build 16299.15. What version of W10 you have?

Comment: What Explorer shell extensions do you in fact have? (Use Nirsoft's ShExView to manage them.)

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it is on a network drive (Samba/Linux), thought I was testing locally.  Windows version is 1809 build 17763.107.  Doesn't happen on a local drive.

Comment: See [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), tab "Explorer" to get an idea of all extensions.

Comment: ShExView list is huge (269 items), going through it abit.  I attached the Autoruns one.  Mainly google drive, foxit, notepad++ and 7zip.  DeskMenu keeps icons in their spots... that might be it.

Comment: Looks like it is Google Drive.  If I disable the GDContextMenu under HKLM\Software\Classes\Directory\ShellExt\ContextMenuHandlers, then the problem disappears.

Comment: Does it bother you to keep it disabled? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I disabled it, I donot need the functionality it offers (Share folder on google drive).  Tested several times now, it definitely looks like the culprit.

Comment: I summarized our exchange in an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the problem: Date in a Samba share was modified by a right-click
in Windows Explorer, even when cancelling immediately the menu.

The tool used to analyze all extension was
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns),
where on the "Explorer" tab one can get the list of all extensions,
then disable one-by-one all those that may relate.

Culprit found : Google Drive, found in the entry named `GDContextMenu`,
listed in Autoruns in more than one place.

Solution: In Autoruns, uncheck the check-box next to `GDContextMenu` to disable
the Google Drive extension.
The entry will still be shown by Autoruns, so can be restored if in the future
you wish to re-enable Google Drive.